# Post data from React Js to Django Rest

Tags: reactjs, django-rest-framework

I am trying to post data from react js to django rest api, but getting http 400 bad request error ("the request could not be processed by the server due to invalid syntax.")

I have tried to refactor my code, and I can't find what the problem is,Here below my code is

```
class Postjob extends React.Component{
constructor(props){
    super(props);
    this.submitForm=this.submitForm.bind(this);
    this.postedjob=this.postedjob.bind(this);
    this.state={
        Company:0,
        job_title:"",
        job_description:"",
        salary:0,
        job_status:false,
    }
}

submitForm= (evt) =>{
    evt.preventDefault()
    console.log(this.state.Company)
    const form={
        Company: this.state.Company,
        job_title: this.state.job_title,
        job_description: this.state.job_description,
        salary: this.state.salary,
        job_status: this.state.job_status
    };

    this.postedjob(form)

};

postedjob = (payload)=>{


    fetch(`http://127.0.0.1:8000/job/create_job/`,
        {
            method: 'POST',
            body: JSON.stringify(payload),
            headers: {
                'Content-Type': 'application/json'
            }
        }
    ).then(response => response.json())
};

render() {
    return(
        <div>
            <h1>{this.state.currenttask}</h1>
            <form onSubmit={this.submitForm}>

                <input type='number' value={this.state.Company} onChange={e=>this.setState({Company:e.target.value})}/>

              <input type='text' value={this.state.job_title} onChange={e=>this.setState({job_title:e.target.value})}/>


                <input type='text' value={this.state.job_description} onChange={e=>this.setState({job_description:e.target.value})}/>

                <input type='number' value={this.state.salary} onChange={e=>this.setState({salary:e.target.value})}/>

                <button type="submit">Submit</button>

          </form>

        </div>
    )
}
```

}

Django Side:

Views.py:

```
lass Companylist(APIView):

 def get(self,request):
   return Response([CompanySerializer(company).data for company in Company.objects.all()])

  def post(self,request):
   payload=request.data
   serializer=CompanySerializer(data=payload)

   if serializer.is_valid():
       serializer.save()
       return Response(serializer.data,status=status.HTTP_201_CREATED)
   return Response(serializer.errors,status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
```

Serializers.py:

```
class CompanySerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

class Meta:
    model=Company
    fields='__all__' #to get all fields

def create(self, validated_data):
    company = Company.objects.all(**validated_data)
    return company

def update(self, instance, validated_data):
    for k, v in validated_data.items():
        setattr(instance, k, v)
        instance.save()
    return instance

def validate(self, attrs):
    if not attrs.get('company_name') or attrs.get('company_name') < 10:
        raise ValidationError("Book is too small to read")
    return attrs
```

I have tried posting from django api and it is doing successfully but when I try from react js form, it giving me error and I can't find the reason.
Will be really thankful if someone can find the cause of error.

Comment: Can you share what's going on on the Django side of things?

Comment: Django part shared.

Comment: Would be good to see your Django Models, please. Do you have any foreign keys in your models? Serialisation  needs to add depth if so.

Comment: Also, non of your form fields have a name attribute, which is what populates request.data. Also, I advise researching React class properties, this will stop you from having to bind in your constructors.

Answer (score 0):

It would be because of wrong types when serializing payload to json.
Are you sure about everything? Does Company field start with uppercase at the server? Should it be a number? if so, you should be aware of type of state values when stringifying payload.

For example the value provided inside of onChange's **event.target.value** will have the type *string* even if the input type is number

You would also like to take a look at this [CodeSandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/nwp068xm5p) I created.